# Flask app not using config file settings properly

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the guide [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/) trying to create a config.py file for my flask app's settings but it is not working.

```
from flask import Flask

# creates the application
def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('instance.config.DevelopmentConfig')

    # home
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return str(app.config['DEBUG']) # displays 'False'
        # return str(app.config['SECRET_KEY']) -- displays 'dev'

    return app
```

my `instance/config.py` file

```
class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'dev'
```

When I do `flask run` it runs the server in production with debug off. I'm not using `export FLASK_ENV` because I am under the impression that it isn't needed when you have a `config.py` file.

Is my assumption wrong? Why is it correctly recording the `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` but not the `DEBUG` mode?

Comment: how do you know it's not correctly recording the `DEBUG` value?

Comment: because I set it to `DEBUG = True` in the `config.py` file yet it displays `'False'` on the `/` route. I'm new to Flask so maybe I am missing some fundamental concepts on how the `config.py` file is supposed to work? edit: or also that the server is running in `production` with `debug=off` when I execute `flask run`

Comment: you shouldn't be setting this in code. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#DEBUG

Comment: Interesting, but then why do they do it right below? I've also seen other Stack Overflow users use it. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#development-production

Comment: I still face the same issue. `flask run` just ignores options like `DEBUG` & `ENV`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#environment-and-debug-features) you shouldn't set Debug and ENV via code, otherwise, some extension can misunderstand that and act unexpectedly.

You still can set it via code and it may work using something like "python main.py" but again according to the documentation...

> While it is possible to set ENV and DEBUG in your config or code, this is strongly discouraged. They can’t be read early by the flask command, and some systems or extensions may have already configured themselves based on a previous value.

The **correct** way of doing that is by using your terminal

Linux:

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Windows:

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Your config.py files should be more related to your database and API secrets keys.

Comment: Yup, this was a long time ago when I was still new with Flask and I wasn't understanding properly what each config was for. This is the right answer and what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I found out that all works fine using `python run.py` instead of `flask run`.

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue when following many tutorials online. Tried set `FLASK_ENV=development` but still didn't work.

Ended up removing the `ENV` and `DEBUG` statements inside the `config.py`, and typed `$env:FLASK_ENV='development'` in the terminal and it finally worked with 'flask run'

Suggest to try `$env:FLASK_ENV='development'` if you're new to Flask like me.
maybe some expert could help explain why only this worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few weeks ago. I solved my problem doing like that:

```
from flask import Flask
from instance.config import DevelopmentConfig # import config object


# creates the application
def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

    # code ...

    return app
```

Comment: tried that, server is still being run in production with debug mode off

Comment: I think your "ENV" variable is incorrect. Try "FLASK_ENV" instead.

Comment: I got it straight from the documentation. I have tried FLASK_ENV without success.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. It's not FLASK_ENV, that's detecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using is to set the `os.environ['FLASK_ENV']` variable in my code.

```py
from flask import Flask

# creates the application
def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('instance.config.DevelopmentConfig')

    # home
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return str(app.config['DEBUG']) # displays 'False'
        # return str(app.config['SECRET_KEY']) -- displays 'dev'

    return app
```

my `instance/config.py` file

```py
import os

class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'dev'
```

```py
# file: commands.py
import os

import click
from click import pass_context
from flask.cli import with_appcontext, run_command

from flask import current_app

@click.command('serve', context_settings={"ignore_unknown_options": True})
@with_appcontext
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def serve(args):
    """Alias for 'flask run'."""
    os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] = current_app.config['ENV']
    ctx = run_command.make_context('serve', list(args))
    run_command.invoke(ctx)
```

```py
# file: wsgi.py
# +++++++++++ FLASK +++++++++++
# This file lets you run 'flask' commands (e.g. flask routes)

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from app import app as application  # noqa
```

Now `flask serve` behaves I expected `flask run` to work. I regard this as a flask bug.